Create a MS Access Pivot Query that returns rows even if there are null values
I'm trying to create a pivot table in MS Access based on an Employee List table, a Skills list table, and a table that contains data on what employee has what level of training for each skill. The table should return default values if there is no row found in the still level table.
Employee Table
ID EmployeeName
1  David
2  Bob
3  Steven
4  Richard


Skills List Table
ID SkillName
1  Skill 1
2  Skill 2
3  Skill 3
4  Skill 5 

SkillsTable
ID  EmployeeID  SkillID  SkillLevel
1   1           1        3
2   3           4        2   

What I need for a final result looks like this. If there's no record found, then 1 is the default skill level.
           Skill 1    Skill 2   Skill 3   Skill 4   Skill 5
David        3           1         1        1         1
Bob          1           1         1        1         1  
Steven       1           1         1        2         1
Richard      1           1         1        1         1 

Basically, even though there's no row in the Skills Table, I should still get all employees and all skill names returned.
Hopefully that makes sense. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate the help. thanks
I created an SQL that gives me a pivot, but it's only returning data if there are rows found in the Skills table, I'm not getting all the employee names or all of the skill names.

You need to make sure that the skills table is on the left of a left join (or the right side of a right join)

@tinazmu, takes more than JOIN type to assure records return for all employees and all skills - even if no employees have a particular skill.

The following SQL will give you the result you were looking for. Note that I removed the space from the Skills List table name so that it is now called SkillsList:
TRANSFORM First(IIf(Nz([SkillsTable].[SkillLevel])<>"",[SkillsTable].[SkillLevel],1)) AS SkillLvl
SELECT qryEmpSkill.EmployeeName
FROM (SELECT Employee.EmployeeName, Employee.ID, SkillsList.ID, SkillsList.SkillName FROM Employee, SkillsList)  AS qryEmpSkill 
LEFT JOIN SkillsTable ON (qryEmpSkill.SkillsList.ID = SkillsTable.SkillID) AND (qryEmpSkill.Employee.ID = SkillsTable.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY qryEmpSkill.EmployeeName
ORDER BY qryEmpSkill.EmployeeName
PIVOT qryEmpSkill.SkillName;


Be aware this involves a Cartesian relationship of two tables which can perform slowly with large dataset. The output you want calls for a dataset of all possible pairs of employees and skills - Cartesian relationship generates that set.

@June, Yes, I know however it does meet the brief. On the face of it, this looks like the dataset will be quite small. If it is significantly larger then David can always filter the employees by department for example. I also do not imagine that all skill sets within a company would be applied to each employee so again some kind of filtering would help. It would be quite humorous to see the janitor with a CEO skill set ;-). Thanks and appreciate your input.

@June7, I realised that I had gotten your name wrong and can no longer edit my comment. Please see my comment above.

BobS, comment not intended as a criticism (I upvoted your answer), just an alert to OP.

Great! Thank you for your help. Yes, the data set is quite small. There are only 15 or so employees and only a dozen or so skills. We're all Techs in the same department and I just need to track who has what level of training for each skill Techs need to have. I'm pretty sure the CEO won't get listed :)
So even if inefficient, this will certainly be fast enough. The results being correct are more important than instant results.

@June7, I did not take your comment as criticism at all. You made a valid point. And thanks for the upvote.
